# Facebook PHP SDK (latest - 16.1.13) & Access Token

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, laravel

I have the following code:

```
public function get_facebook()
    {
        $loginUrl = Helpers::fbLogin();

        if(Input::get('error'))
        {
            Session::flash('failure', 'You need to give permissions.');
            return Redirect::to('signup');
        }
        else
        {
            $facebook = IoC::resolve('facebook-sdk');
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
            $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');

            $user = User::where('uid', '=', $uid)->or_where('email', '=', $fbuser['email'])->first();

            if(is_null($user)){
                Session::flash('fbuser', $fbuser);
                return Redirect::to('signup');
            } else {
                Auth::login($user);
                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to($loginUrl);
    }
```

But I get this message:
`An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Also when I print the `$facebook->getAccessToken()` & try opening my app with different facebook accounts I get same `token`.

What is `access token` & what do we use it for?

P.S. I have set up properly my appID & secret code. The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access token is token, that is given to your application by user to access his/her information from your application. In order to get that token, user has to give you permission to access at least his basic information.

More [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)

Comment: So a new access token is generated for every user?

Comment: Yes. They also expire after a while so they will be changing constantly for users

Comment: Well, I get only APP's access token, not user. And I think that's why I get this error: `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` Any ideas how to get user's access token?

Comment: pretty simple. You use SDK's ->getLoginUrl() (i belive that's the name of function) and redirect user to that link. It will ask user for permissions and redirect him back, granting your app access token for that user